# UrbanCode Deploy: How to pass in parameters to the "Run Application Process" plugin?

Tags: urbancode

Is there a way to pass in parameters to the "Run Application Process" plugin? I have an application A's Application Process wants to invoke an application B's Application Process (which calls its Component Process requires two inputs from the user).

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS4GSP_6.0.1/com.ibm.udeploy.plugins.doc/topics/ucd_applications_runapplicationprocess.html

Answer (score 0):

Not directly in the plugin step. What you can do is setting a component environment property (or application or component property) before running the application process. You'd need to handle the user input in Application A's process, set the properties for Application B and then run Application B's process.

Comment: How to "set the properties for Application B and then run Application B's process." in this case? This is the key. CLI, REST API?

Comment: And if I use CLI/REST, how do I know if the application process execution is successful or not? https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS4GSP_6.1.0/com.ibm.udeploy.api.doc/topics/udclient_requestapplicationprocess.html

Comment: In a component in App1, you create a step "Create Application Property". You specify AppB as application, propertyB's name and as value ${p:appAProcessProp}.